# Bootstrap Modal Not popping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I'm currently learning Bootstrap and I just placed a chunk of code of Modal component into my project.  However, after I run the program, I found it was not working and the button was not responding as it was supposed to be.  So I'm just wondering if anybody who could help me with it? I'll be appreciate it very much.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap requires jQuery. If you would open developer tools for any browser you are using, you would see the error in console.

Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>` to your html

Comment: Thank you John, I tried to put the script at the bottom of my code and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

maybe you just forgot to include bootstrapjs and jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="<your path to js file>bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Moein, I just checked my code and found the script was put in the <head> tag. Even though I'm not hundred percent sure it is due to the reason of that, but I believe it may have some connects to my issue which made the modal didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleakarsh/6o0spz8g/
 
                                                            Launch demo modal

```
                                                    <!-- Modal -->
                                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                                    ...
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: your code is entirely working fine. check whether you have added bootstrap.js,jquery.js and css file or cdn links. Make sure that, JQuery cdn link is placed above the bootstrap link

Comment: Thank you Akarsh, I just moved the script from the <head> to the bottom of my code and it worked.  From this point, I'm just wondering if you know why it is causing this problem? Also, when I was moving the code, I tried to move the CSS file as well and even though it worked at the end, I realized the decoration of the page showed up after a flash, which means it was first just a plain page without any styles, then after a quick flash of the page, the style showed up.

Comment: i am not clear of you question,any how Here are a few points: always keep the links or scripts pertaining to angular and angular related,jquery,bootstrap,and bootstrap css in head section. Remaining scripts or links of controllers,factories ,directives etc in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot jQuery simply add

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```